# Cocoa Java compilation failure in XCode 3.2

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I developed an application in using Cocoa using Xcode 3.1. Now I upgraded the OS version and tried to compile the code in Xcode 3.2, but the app crashes with an error:

> CocoaJava: com.apple.cocoa.foundation.NSRuntime
>   -[NSJavaVirtualMachine initWithClassPath:] FATAL: cannot initialize ObjCJava

I still dont know how to resolve this. Please any one help me....

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?JavaBridge) Cocoa Java runtime support has been removed in 10.6 (scroll to the bottom). That page also has a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

CocoaJava was deprecated in 10.4.

I wouldn't be surprised if it has been completely removed in 10.6.

**Important:** The Cocoa-Java API is deprecated in Mac OS X version 10.4 and later. You should use the Objective-C API instead; this API is documented in *Application Kit Framework Reference* and *Foundation Framework Reference*.

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LanguageIntegration/LanguageIntegration.html